# watir cannot create internet explorer browser - Enable Protected Mode issue

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using the following code snippets to create internet explorer browser and do some testing. I am not able to create ie browser because of the exception given below. How do I fix this?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'phantomjs'

client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 300

browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie, :http_client => client
browser.goto "some url"
```

Error -

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.29.0.0
Listening on port 5555
C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok': Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError)
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:629:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:98:in `create_session'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/ie/bridge.rb:47:in `initialize'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:35:in `new'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:35:in `for'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
        from C:/code/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from web-test.rb:8:in `new'
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any ruby code which will fix this problem. But, I learned that you can change your IE settings to fix this problem - http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html

How to set Protected Mode settings

In IE, from the Tools menu (or the gear icon in the toolbar in later versions), select "Internet options." Go to the Security tab. At the bottom of the dialog for each zone, you should see a check box labeled "Enable Protected Mode." Set the value of the check box to the same value, either checked or unchecked, for each zone. Here's the dialog for reference:

[image: Here's the dialog for reference:]