# Error::SessionNotCreatedError: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, internet-explorer-11, watir

Unable launch Internet Explorer using my script it gives this error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones.
```

I researched a lot to get work around for this and found few solutions https://stackoverflow.com/a/29453294/1976848, but I am unable to change my IE browser settings, The checkbox to `"Enable Protected mode"` is disabled for all the zones here
[image]

Also, tried to override this with desired capabilities here is the code but not getting any success:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.internet_explorer(
                     :ignoreProtectedModeSettings => true,
                     :javascriptEnabled => true,
                 )
Watir::Browser.new :ie, http_client: client,:desired_capabilities => caps
```

I am using Cucumber with Ruby and Watir and Browser is Internet Explorer 11.

Please suggest some workaround for this.

Comment: Maybe Protected mode is enabled for one of the security zone. I suggest you to again check it for all the zone and try to disabled it. If issue persist then you can try to contact your system administrator to help you to modify it.

Comment: The issue is resolved, First I tried to fix it by editing the registry specific to the browser's options but that too I don't have permission. Then I tried a way to modify it using script and found a reference "Power Shell" script to modify it from here https://stackoverflow.com/q/51720030 and after some tweaks in the script, it works :D

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution for the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Comment: Did that!! Thanks @Deepak-MSFT

Comment: You can also try to accept it as an answer when it is available to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue gets resolved after doing continuous research around it,

1. Most of the Stackoverflow and Github answers shows to change the settings from Internet Options but those are not working from me due to permission limitation
2. One of the blog posts from LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/automation-using-internet-explorer-11-pritam-maske. Suggested to modify the registry specific to internet explorer, but that too I am unable to edit due to permission limitations.
3. Taking the points from registry modification, then I found a way to edit it via `PowerShell script` and found few solutions to reset the Internet Explorer Preferences from Microsoft power shell script repositories
   [How to reset all Internet Explorer settings for a different user profile?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/508360d9-812c-4fb9-83d2-6d98c7b9905a/how-to-reset-all-internet-explorer-8-settings-for-a-different-user-profile?forum=ieitprocurrentver)
4. With this got 1 step success but main problem remains same i.e. my IE 11 not launched, then searched for to "Enable the Protected Mode for all Zones" and got few post with a good description around it

   a. [Powershell – IE zones Protected Mode state](https://x86x64.wordpress.com/2014/05/20/powershell-ie-zones-protected-mode-state/)

   b. [IE Browser - Powershell script to add a site to trusted sites list, disable protected mode & make all zones security level low](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720030/ie-browser-powershell-script-to-add-site-to-trusted-sites-list-disable-protec)

   At last, after doing tweaks in the Powershell script it works and my script is working fine for IE browser.